# How to make the substr() only work in those words that are over the word limit?

Tags: php, substr

Currently I am using

```
substr("String name", 0, 10).'...'
```

To replace any words that are more than 10 with ...

However I realise that even I use it on simple word like "Bond"

```
substr("Bond", 0, 10).'...';
```

The "..." will still appear, how can I make it that only words that is over the word limit can have "..."

Comment: Cant you just check the string length and only do the substr if the length is greater than the desired length?

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "bond";

if(strlen($string) > 10)
    $string = substr($string, 0, 10) . '...';
```

Answer (score 1):

To see if the string is longer than a certain length, do this:

```
$string = "Applepie is delicious.";
$maxlength = 10;

// If the string length is bigger than $maxlength
if(strlen($string) > $maxlength)
{
    echo substr($string, 0, $maxlength).'...';
}

// If it's shorter than $maxlength
else
{
    echo $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may help:

```
function str_curtail($str, $length = 35, $append = '...')
{
    // String short enough already ?
    if (strlen($str) <= $length) {
        return $str;
    }
    $str = substr($str, 0, $length);
    for ($i=$length - 1; !ctype_space($str{$i}); --$i); // No body intentionally
    $str = rtrim(substr($str, 0, $i));
    return $str . $append;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a quick regex:

```
$str = 'Hello world what is up';
preg_replace('/(.{10}).+/', '$1...', $str); //=> "Hello worl..."
```

If there aren't at least 10 characters then it won't do anything since the capture group won't match.

Comment: I don't see why not. Regex are a tool for string manipulation, and this is a string.

Comment: By that logic I should use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. My point is, there are *better* tools for the job (e.g. core string functions).

Comment: Perhaps because it's overkill, an expensive sledgehammer when a ball-pean will do.

Comment: lol. I see your point. I often forget how all these `str!@#$%` functions work, "haystack", "needle", "subject" or the other way around? underscore or no underscore? Not that you need anything very complex for this task but `preg_*` is instant thinking.

Comment: And sometimes one gets an ego-boost from coming up with a "clever" solution.  RE solutions sometimes feel better because they're more terse, but you forget about all that's going on under the scenes to run that one-liner, just to save two lines of simple code.